# php nested error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

The following is in reference to the fictional functions shown below.

```
public function a()
{
    try {
        $this->b();
        $this->c();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}

public function b()
{
    //some error here
}

public function c()
{
    //some error here
}
```

I am trying to run something like this

`$this->a();`

Why is it that when I try and run nested functions like this it doesn't catch the error effectively? It will still show a php fatal error in either function `b()` or `c()`.

Do i also need to place a try catch within the other 2 functions?

Comment: try-catch is for exceptions, fatal errors are unrecoverable errors that can't be caught
If you want to register a handler for them use `register_shutdown_function()`

Comment: Can you give an example of the errors your trying to trap.